# How to calculate New Fans from Total Fans using dates in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I am pulling Facebook Fan data daily via Supermetrics into Data Studio and I was hoping someone could share a formula that I could use to calculate New Fans, as a calculated field, from Total Fans.

The formula would need Identify the last day of the month and the subtract followers from the first day of the month.

For example: If there 100 Fans at the end of September and 60 Fans at the beginning September, the formula would show 40 New Fans.

**Formula Example**

[image: Formula Example]

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the net fan numbers is always increasing, first set the aggregation method for `Total Fans` to `None` in Fields screen by editing the data source. Then you can create a new calculated metric with the formula `max(Total Fans)-min(Total Fans)`. This will work only at aggregate level (using scorecard or table total) and not at row level in tables.